# Which interworking modes does Tuya Cloud support?

Tags: iot, tuya

Recently, I am searching for a suitable IoT platform to implement my Cloud startup ideas. Amazon AWS IoT, Microsoft Azure IoT and Apple HomeKit are the popular ones, but they are all serving their own closed ecosystems. An interesting platform named Tuya Cloud: https://developer.tuya.com/en/cloud attracts me. But I don't know which interworking modes does it support?

Answer (score 0):

The Tuya Cloud Platform (https://developer.tuya.com/en/cloud) provides various integrate modes based on Tuya's mature IoT services, combining different docking scenarios:

1. Simple mode (implicit authorization):

Tuya Cloud provides a cloud-based docking method based on the oauth2 protocol. Developers can apply for a cloud API on the tuya IoT platform, call tuya openapi according to the tuya openapi interface specification, obtain the developer's own user and device data, and control the device through permissions.

For this case, developers need to create OEM applications or create products on the platform. After that, you can get user data or device data based on your development account.

2、Authorization code mode (explicit authorization):

After applying the cloud API key on Tuya cloud platform, developers can call Tuya open interface based on Tuya openapi interface specification to obtain resource data and authorization scope under authorization Resource data.

For cloud integration scenarios where there is no OEM application in the tuya platform, tuya cloud provides an authorization code method.